# Wix Bundle bal:Condition is not evaluated

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bundle

I have bundle:

```
<Bundle Name="$(var.TOOLBOX_PRODUCT_NAME)" 
        Version="$(var.TOOLBOX_VERSION)" 
        Manufacturer="$(var.COMPANY_NAME)" 
        UpgradeCode="upgrade_code"
        IconSourceFile="$(var.TargetDir)..\..\..\..\VisualizationApp\src\Icon.ico"
        DisableModify="yes">
```

And the following condition is not evaluated ever:

```
<bal:Condition Message="Application requires 64-bit Windows 10 or higher.">
   <![CDATA[VersionNT >= v10.0 AND VersionNT64]]>
</bal:Condition>
```

Also any other bal:Condition does not make any difference to my installation.
Is it a problem that I am using following?

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id='ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost'>
```

On the other hand if I put bundle Property

```
Condition="VersionNT &gt;= v10.1 AND VersionNT64"
```

It gives me a generic message

> The specified program requires a newer version of Windows.